# What does the "C" symbol means in EER diagrams?

Tags: database-design, diagram, eer-model

What does the "C" symbol that exists for example in disjoint in EER diagrams mean. I don't ask what disjoint mean I'm just interested in what the "C"-symbol means? I assume that it's not a union? So what is it then?

http://web.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/course/cse670/cse670Ch16.xht

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean the "C"-like symbol thy put on the lines used for expressing subtypes, right? This seems to stand for the set inclusion symbol (recall that A ⊂ B means that A is a subset of B) for indicating subclassing/subtyping/subseting.